# About SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I need to develop a news slider app or add-in. My development platform is SharePoint 2013. with my research, i realized that i can do it with three options. SharePoint Hosted App, Provider Hosted App or Solution. I tried to develop with SharePoint Hosted Add-in. For data source i used publishing pages feature. But the problem is when i have developed with the javascript (jquery, rest and csom), my add-in starts after page load because of native of client side scripting. For my need, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

yeah thats the beaviour you are describing for a typical SP hosted Add-In, it loads after by its nature. Is that not ok for you? For this kind of requirement I should go for the SP Hosted Add-In. Optionally, if you have the Content Search Web Part, this is a way to go - building a display template with a control template. More option.. Use a content editor web part and link to a JS file where you have the markup and JS.